# How to run a function from EJS template?

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm trying to use a checkVowel() function from an ejs template. But it's not working.

I'm getting a string input from home.ejs:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Just enter a string and I will tell you how many vowels are there...</h1>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <label for="strInput">Enter text</label>
        <input type="text" id="strInput" name="str">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Here's the JavaScript part that I've added in functions.ejs:

```
<% function checkVowel(str) {
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    vowel_count = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { if (vowels.includes(str[i])) { vowel_count += 1; } } console.log(`There are ${vowel_count} vowels in the provided string.`)
} %>
```

I am parsing my data from Express using req.body.

```
const express = require('express')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// View engine setup 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
// app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const {str} = req.body;
    res.render('result', {str})
    // res.send(`Okay, checking: ${str}`)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I'm really confused about how to run my function. I don't know whether to include it in a .ejs file or create a separate folder and use express.static().

What I want to do it when someone fills the form in my home.ejs file. The string is used as an argument in my checkVowel() function and then I render the vowel_count in my ejs template.

Comment: `const vowel_count = (str.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length;`

Answer (score 0):

So after a ton of trial and error, I figured out what was wrong. I needed to add the EJS tags where necessary. For some reason, console.log doesn't work for EJS templates. The following code works fine:

```
<% function checkVowel(str) { %>
    <% let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']  %>
    <% let vowel_count = 0 %>
    <% str = str.toLowerCase() %>
    <% for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { %>
        <% if (vowels.includes(str[i])) { %> 
            <% vowel_count +=1; %>
        <% } %> 
    <% } %>
    <p> There are <%= vowel_count %> vowels in the provided string.</p> <% } %>

<%= checkVowel(str) %>
```

I'm passing the **str** parameter using a form.